# Regex to remove string from string

Tags: c#, regex

Is there a regex pattern that can remove `.zip.ytu` from the string below?

```
werfds_tyer.abc.zip.ytu_20111223170226_20111222.20111222
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use [`String.Replace()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx)

```
String.Replace(".zip.ytu", "");
```

You don't need regex for exact matches.

Comment: OP asked for a solution involving a regex. Years later I come here looking for a solution with a regex. You are correct but this doesn't answer OPs or my question.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have javascript to fix the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an answer using regex as the OP asked.

To use regex, put the replacment text in a match `( )` and then replace that match with nothing `string.Empty`:

```
string text = @"werfds_tyer.abc.zip.ytu_20111223170226_20111222.20111222";
string pattern = @"(\.zip\.ytu)";

Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace(text, pattern, string.Empty ));

// Outputs 
// werfds_tyer.abc_20111223170226_20111222.20111222
```

Comment: This is the actual answer to the question. 

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for.  I'm not looking for exact matches, but regex pattern removal.

Answer (score 2):

```
txt = txt.Replace(".zip.ytu", "");
```

Why don't you simply do above?

Answer (score 2):

Don't really know what is the ".zip.ytu", but if you don't need exact matches, you might use something like that:

```
string txt = "werfds_tyer.abc.zip.ytu_20111223170226_20111222.20111222";

Regex mRegex = new Regex(@"^([^.]*\.[^.]*)\.[^.]*\.[^_]*(_.*)$");
Match mMatch = mRegex.Match(txt);

string new_txt = mRegex.Replace(txt, mMatch.Groups[1].ToString() + mMatch.Groups[2].ToString());
```

Comment: [^.]* (Zero to unlimited) of not a period. Why kill the regex parser with the '*', specifically as the zero condition being valid? Instead, use of the '+' saying -1- to many would provide a better hint and not cause back tracking. Do you really believe that there will be nothing followed by a period; or do you believe that at least 1 character will exist? If you believe that 1 character will exist, then use that and not the *. HTH

Comment: I wrote that i don't really know what is the ".zip.ytu", and, well, i don't know what the whole string is. So, i could admit that this string might be something like "..test1.test2_123123.123123", because of why not? If i really know that there always should be something between these dots, then, of course, i would use "+" instead of "*". What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

use string.Replace:

```
txt = txt.Replace(".zip.ytu", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I use for more complex repaces.  Check out the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx for a Regular Expression replace. I added the code below as well.

```
  string input = "This is   text with   far  too   much   " + 
                 "whitespace.";
  string pattern = "\\s+";
  string replacement = " ";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input);
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result);
```